# Java impose final programmatically

Tags: java, final

What's the proper way to ensure a value only gets set once, although the time it will be set is unknown (ie: not in the constructor). I could do a null check or keep track of a flag and throw an exception - but what exception should I throw? It's for a small, localized library and I prefer not to create my own ValueAlreadyAssigned exception for such a seemingly generic case.

Comment: I would **not** recommend throwing standard exceptions since there may come a point where you are actually handling these and then you won't know if you threw it yourself illegally. There's nothing wrong with creating an exception class for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method could throw `IllegalStateException`, since it's javadocs say:

> Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal inappropriate
>   time.

Answer (score 8):

In the setter. Do it like this:

```
private foo bar;

public void setFoo(foo bar) {
    if (this.bar == null) {
        this.bar = bar;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Don't touch me!");
        // J/K Throw an IllegalStateException as Michal Borek said in his answer.
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure who answered first :P But IllegalStateException seems okay. I was under the impression that was not completely appropriate as it wasn't so much an "inappropriate time" as an integrity error (client should only call this once)

Comment: The setter is not thread safe, could add some synchronizing code:)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO definition of your own exception is not a big deal especially if it extends `RuntimeException`. So I'd suggest you to define `ValueAlreadySetException extends IllegalStateException` and use it.

The next point is the logic into each setter you have to duplicate according to @Renan's suggestion. I'd suggest you the following. Define special generic container and use it:

```
public class SetOnceContainer<T> {
    private Class<T> type;
    private String name;
    private T value;
    private boolean set = false;

    public SetOnceContainer(Class<T> type, String name) {
        this.type = type;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void set(T value) {
        if (set) {
             throw new ValueAlreadySetException(name);
        }
        this.value = value;
        this.set = true;
    }
    public T get() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Please pay attention that this implementation supports `null` values too.

Now you can use it as following:

```
public MyClass {
    private SetOnceContainer<Integer> number = new SetOnceContainer<Integer>(Integer.class, "number");
    private SetOnceContainer<String> text = new SetOnceContainer<String>(String.class, "text");


    public void setNumber(int value) {
        number.set(value);
    }
    public void setText(String value) {
        text.set(value);
    }
    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number.get();
    }
    public String getText() {
        text.get();
    }
}
```

The implementation is encapsulated into once point. You can change it in once place if you need. Null values are supported too. The setters and getters are just a little bit more complicated than regular.

Comment: I think for my purposes I'll use IllegalStateException, but I didn't think of a generic wrapper. +1